# Three Cornered Duel -- Different Solution?

Tags: probability, game-theory

So there is the famous [Three-Cornered Duel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042698/the-three-cornered-duel) problem from the book "Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solution" by Frederick Mosteller. It was answered in the thread provided but I approached it in a different way and reached the same answer. I was wondering if this is a correct approach.

First of all, the question and answer (quoted from the book):

**The problem**

> A, B and C are to fight a three-cornered pistol duel. All know that
>   A's chance of hitting his target is 0.3, C's is 0.5, and B never
>   misses. They are to fire at their choice of target in succession in
>   the order A, B, C, cyclically (but a hit man loses further turns and
>   is no longer shot at) until only one man is left unit. What should A's
>   strategy be?

**Mosteller's solution:**

> A is naturally not feeling cheery about this enterprise. Having the
>   first shot he sees that, if he hits C, B will then surely hit him, and
>   so he is not going to shoot at C. If he shoots at B and misses him,
>   then B clearly shoots the more dangerous C first, and A gets one shot
>   at B with probability 0.3 of succeeding. If he misses this time, the
>   less said the better. On the other hand, suppose A hits B.  Then C and
>   A shoot alternately until one hits. A's chance of winning is
>   $$(.5)(.3)+(.5)^2(.7)(.3)+(.5)^3(.7)^2(.3)+…$$
>   Each term corresponds to a sequence of misses by both C and A ending with a final hit by A. Summing the geometric series we get
>   $$(.5)(.3)+\{1+(.5)(.7)+[(.5)(.7)]^2+… \}= \frac{(.5)(.3)}{1-(.5)(.7)}= \frac{0.15}{0.65}= \frac{3}{13} < \frac{3}{10}$$ 
>   Thus hitting B and finishing off with C has less
>   probability of winning for A than just missing the first shot. So A
>   fires his first shot into the ground and then tries to hit B with his
>   next shot. C is out of luck.

**My Approach**

All these answer think of the probability of winning given if A succeeds or fails at who they target. The stack exchange thread linked solves for $P(A_{win} | A \ hits\ B)$ and $P(A_{win} | A \ misses\ B)$.

Shouldn't we be thinking in terms of $P(A_{win} | A \ targets\ B)$? It's the same logic more or less, but in this case we take into account the probability that A can both hit and miss B vs. the probability that he just waits until B kills C and then tries to kill him directly.

Some probabilities I will use for the below proof (from Mosteller's book)

$P(AvsC) = P(A_{win} | \text{infinite shootout with C}) $

$P(AvsC) = P(C_{miss}) * (P(A_{hit}) + P(A_{miss})P(AvsC))$

solving for $P(AvsC)$, we have $P(AvsC) = \frac{3}{13}$

So that would be:

```
                            -- P(hits B AND AvsC) = P(hits B) * P(AvsC) = 0.3 * 3/13 = ~0.069
                           /
                          /
P (A_win | A targets B) =
                          \
                           \
                            -- P(miss B AND hits B the 2nd try) = P(A_miss) * P(A_hit) =0.7 * 0.3 = 0.21
```

So if A *targets* B on his first shot, he will win with probability $\approx 0.279$

But if he just fires at the fround, he will hit him the second time around with probability = 0.3

So he should fire at the ground.

Is that a valid approach? Isn't that a better approach? I get that Mosteller's Solution basically normalizes for A firing at B, but isn't that a wrong approach? I dunno... my logic just makes more sense to me. I'd never be able to think like the book solution if I were given this problem with no answer.... trying to learn new ways to think!

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.